# ¿Cómo iterar un json y extraer información en java?

Tags: java, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo un problema, espero y me puedan ayudar, lo que sucede es que tengo este método:

```
private String[][] obtenerMatriz() {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader ("D:/Usuarios/JBustamante/Desktop/C0_2019-05-31_927837_0.json"));
        System.out.println("Cadena completa json del archivo..." + obj);

        JSONObject jsonObjectArchivo = (JSONObject)obj;//se guarda en la variable jsonObject la cadena json del archivo
        Object objJson = jsonObjectArchivo.get("opciones");
        if(objJson instanceof JSONArray){
            System.out.println("Esto es un array de opciones"); 
            JSONArray obj2 =  (JSONArray)objJson;   
            obj2.iterator().next();             
        }
        String cadenaArchivoJson= "";

        if(objJson != null){
            cadenaArchivoJson= objJson.toString();
        }else{
            cadenaArchivoJson= "";
        }

        System.out.println("Cadenita json Archv "+ cadenaArchivoJson);  

    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que recorrer simultáneamente un `json` que viene desde un archivo, y extraer información de ese `json` del arreglo, por ejm en donde "opciones"[....], trae cierta información y hay otra "Transacciones"[...] como puedo iterar en base al código de arriba, es que donde me basé es muy sencillo y no es están complejo como lo requiero, este es mi `json` de archivo que extraigo:

```
{
  "folioReferencia" : "42667C002",
  "folioEvento" : "92218",
  "tipoMensaje" : "Replace",
  "claveCotizacion" : "ADP",
  "razonSocial" : "AEROPORTS DE PARIS",
  "serie" : "N",
  "isin" : "FR0010340141",
  "mercadoPrincipal" : "EURONEXT PARIS",
  "tipoEvento" : "CashDividend",
  "indicador" : "Mandatory",
  "completo" : "COMPLETE",
  "confirmado" : "CONFIRMED",
  "fechaExdate" : "07\/06\/2019",
  "fechaRegistro" : "10\/06\/2019",
  "tipoEventos" : [ {
    "qualifierDescription" : "Occurrence Type",
    "indicatorDescription" : "FINAL"
  } ],
  "opciones" : [ {
    "numero" : 1,
    "tipo" : "Cash",
    "default" : "true",
    "transacciones" : [ {
      "transaccion" : "Cash Movement",
      "fechaPago" : "11\/06\/2019",
      "creditoDebito" : "Credit",
      "importeBruto" : {
        "amount" : 3.0,
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "rateType" : "TaxablePortion"
      },
      "importeNeto" : {
        "amount" : 2.1,
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "rateType" : "TaxablePortion"
      },
      "retencion" : {
        "percent" : "30.0"
      }
    } ]
  } ],
  "notas" : {
    "addtlTxt" : ""
  }
}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, la verdad nunca he hecho esto y prácticamente soy nuevo en esto, quedo al pendiente si algo no queda claro, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para tema de Json, soy mas partidario de [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), ya que me resulta mas intuitivo.

Practicamente ya lo tenias hecho y solo tenias que seguir haciendo los cosas que ya habias hecho.

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader ("source/file.json"));
        System.out.println("Cadena completa json del archivo..." + obj);

        JSONObject jsonObjectArchivo = (JSONObject)obj;//se guarda en la variable jsonObject la cadena json del archivo
        Object objJson = jsonObjectArchivo.get("opciones");
        if(objJson instanceof JSONArray){
            System.out.println("Esto es un array de opciones"); 
            JSONArray obj2 =  (JSONArray)objJson; 
            //Recorremos en array, ya que sabemos su tamaño  
            for(int i = 0; i< obj2.size();i++)
            {            

                JSONArray transacciones = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) obj2.get(i)).get("transacciones");
                //Aqui tienes las transacciones y haces con ellas lo que quieres.   
                // 
                // ****Lo que quieras hacer con tus transacciones**** 
                //              
            }
        }
        String cadenaArchivoJson= "";

        if(objJson != null){
            cadenaArchivoJson= objJson.toString();
        }else{
            cadenaArchivoJson= "";
        }

        System.out.println("Cadenita json Archv "+ cadenaArchivoJson);  

    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Solo te faltaba recorrer el JSONArray para tener acceso a las transaciones

Comment: Hola buenas tardes amigo, tendrías algún ejemplo para realizar estas transacciones?? Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, por ejm ya está casi completo, siguiendo un ejemplo que vi en internet, hay manera de llenar con esa información tanto del jsonArray y el objeto, en un jtable, he visto que se puede hacer por medio de vectores, practicamente es mi primera vez que trabajo con interfaces graficas de java en este caso JTable, en base a lo que voy que tips me podrías brindar para poder hacer esto? de antemano muchas gracias :)

Comment: Volvi a hacer otra pregunta, es donde es mas detallado:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274987/como-llenar-jtable-de-swing-con-valores-de-un-jsonarray-y-jsonobject-en-java

Comment: Hola buenas. Seguramente te lo van a decir en la otra pregunta. que no crees una nueva pregunta y que modifiques la anterior para añadir la información extra.