# Como llenar jtable de swing con valores de un jsonArray y jsonObject en java?

Tags: java, jtable, hashmap, jsonobject, jsonarray

soy yo de nuevo, ya había hecho esta misma pregunta pero no muy completa lo que pasa es que quiero extraer ciertos valores tanto de un jsonObject y un jsonArray a un jtable de la librería de swing, es mi primera vez que trabajo con interfaces gráficas, ya puedo acceder a los elementos pero de estoy atorado en como meterlos a un jtable

Estoy probando con json:

```
{
  "folioReferencia" : "42667C002",
  "folioEvento" : "92218",
  "tipoMensaje" : "Replace",
  "claveCotizacion" : "ADP",
  "razonSocial" : "AEROPORTS DE PARIS",
  "serie" : "N",
  "isin" : "FR0010340141",
  "mercadoPrincipal" : "EURONEXT PARIS",
  "tipoEvento" : "CashDividend",
  "indicador" : "Mandatory",
  "completo" : "COMPLETE",
  "confirmado" : "CONFIRMED",
  "fechaExdate" : "07\/06\/2019",
  "fechaRegistro" : "10\/06\/2019",
  "tipoEventos" : [ {
    "qualifierDescription" : "Occurrence Type",
    "indicatorDescription" : "FINAL"
  } ],
  "opciones" : [ {
    "numero" : 1,
    "tipo" : "Cash",
    "default" : "true",
    "transacciones" : [ {
      "transaccion" : "Cash Movement",
      "fechaPago" : "11\/06\/2019",
      "creditoDebito" : "Credit",
      "importeBruto" : {
        "amount" : 3.0,
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "rateType" : "TaxablePortion"
      },
      "importeNeto" : {
        "amount" : 2.1,
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "rateType" : "TaxablePortion"
      },
      "retencion" : {
        "percent" : "30.0"
      }
    } ]
  } ],
  "notas" : {
    "addtlTxt" : ""
  }
}
```

Este es mi metodo para armar la tabla en la vista:

```
private void construirTabla(){
        String titulos[]={"TIPO EVENTO SIC","TIPO DERECHO COVACK",
                        "ES_REGIMEN_FISCAL","ORIGEN_DERECHO", 
                        "NOTAS"};

        String informacion[][]=obtenerMatriz();
        miTabla1 = new JTable(informacion,titulos);
        miBarra.setViewportView(miTabla1);

    }
```

Y este es mi metodo donde quiero realizar todo el proceso de llenado:

```
private String[][] obtenerMatriz() {//JJ Metodo con el que estoy trabajando

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        //ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Vector<Vector<String>> dataList = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
         Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();
         HashMap hKey = new HashMap();
        try{
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader ("D:/Usuarios/JBustamante/Desktop/C0_2019-05-31_927837_0.json"));

            System.out.println("Cadena completa json del archivo..." + obj);

            JSONObject jsonObjectArchivo = (JSONObject)obj;//se guarda en la variable jsonObject la cadena json del archivo
            Object objJson = jsonObjectArchivo.get("opciones");
            if(objJson instanceof JSONArray){
                System.out.println("Esto es un array de opciones"); 
                JSONArray obj2 =  (JSONArray)objJson;             

                //Recorremos en array, ya que sabemos su tamaño               
                for(int i = 0; i< obj2.size();i++)
                {            
                    JSONArray transacciones = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) obj2.get(i)).get("transacciones");               


                    //list.add(transacciones.get(i).toString());                 
                    //System.out.println("Prueba recorrido..."+ list.size());                                   
                }
                //String matrizInfo[][] = new String[list.size()][5];

                //Llenado de informacion

            }





            String cadenaArchivoJson= "";

            if(objJson != null){
                cadenaArchivoJson= objJson.toString();
            }else{
                cadenaArchivoJson= "";
            }

            System.out.println("Cadenita json Archv "+ cadenaArchivoJson);  

        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

No sé exactamente como realizarlo, queria que si me pudiera ayudar brindandome algunos tips de como hacerlo teniendo en cuenta mi código que puse arriba, para ser mas especifico, dejo la interfaz grafica de como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte de abajo es donde se debe de mostrar la información que elijo de los valores, he visto que se pueden hacer Vector y hashmap, pero la verdad no sé muy bien como usarlo, he tratado de buscar ejemplos y no logro comprender y usarlos a como lo requiero, si hay forma de que cambie ya sea el tipo de retorno en mi método de obtenerMatriz con gusto estoy abierto, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios, saludos

Anexo avance un detalle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando cree método `procesarTransaccion`me marcaron esos errores, que podría ser amigo, a lo que entiendo es que no encuentra ese metodo, faltaría que se exporte alguna clase?

Comment: parece que tu pregunta ha quedado en el olvido, te recomiendo agregar los imports para que podamos saber de que libreria estas usando jsonobject

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo es crear objetos que contengan lo que se extrae del JSON para que así pueda ser manipulado más fácilmente después.

**Objeto Transaccion**

```
public class Transaccion{
    private String transaccion;
    private String fechaPago;
    private String creditoDebito;
    private Importe importeBruto;
    private Importe importeNeto;
    private String retencion;

    // Constructor, gets y setters del objeto
}
```

**Objeto Importe**

```
public class Importe{
    private double importe;
    private String currency,
    private String rateType;

    //Constructor, gets y setters del objeto
}
```

Lo siguiente es cambiar el metodo obtenerMatriz para sacar los datos del JSON. Optaria por devolver un `ArrayList` ya que es mas comodo que un `String[][]`

```
private ArrayList<Transaccion> obtenerMatriz() {//JJ Metodo con el que estoy trabajando
    ArrayList<Transaccion> list= new ArrayList();//Creamos la lista
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    //ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Vector<Vector<String>> dataList = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
     Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();
     HashMap hKey = new HashMap();
    try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader ("D:/Usuarios/JBustamante/Desktop/C0_2019-05-31_927837_0.json"));

        System.out.println("Cadena completa json del archivo..." + obj);

        JSONObject jsonObjectArchivo = (JSONObject)obj;//se guarda en la variable jsonObject la cadena json del archivo
        Object objJson = jsonObjectArchivo.get("opciones");
        if(objJson instanceof JSONArray){
            System.out.println("Esto es un array de opciones"); 
            JSONArray obj2 =  (JSONArray)objJson;             

            //Recorremos en array, ya que sabemos su tamaño               
            for(int i = 0; i< obj2.size();i++)
            {            
                JSONArray transacciones = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) obj2.get(i)).get("transacciones");               
                //Recorremos cada transaccion una a una
                for(int u = 0; U< transacciones.size();u++)
                {
                    //Llamamos a un nuevo método para procesar la transaccion y así no hacer tan complicado el codigo de este método.
                    list.add(procesarTransaccion(transacciones.get(u)));   
                }                              
            }
        }
        String cadenaArchivoJson= "";

        if(objJson != null){
            cadenaArchivoJson= objJson.toString();
        }else{
            cadenaArchivoJson= "";
        }
        System.out.println("Cadenita json Archv "+ cadenaArchivoJson);  

    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

**El nuevo metodo procesarTransaccion**

```
private Transaccion procesarTransaccion(JSONArray transaccionJson){
    Transaccion transaccion = new Transaccion();

    transaccion.setTransaccion(transaccionJson.containsKey("transaccion")?transaccionJson.get("transaccion"):null);
    transaccion.setFechaPago(transaccionJson.containsKey("fechaPago")?transaccionJson.get("fechaPago"):null);                        
    transaccion.setCreditoDebito(transaccionJson.containsKey("creditoDebito")?transaccionJson.get("creditoDebito"):null);        
    transaccion.setRetencion(transaccionJson.containsKey("retencion")?transaccionJson.get("retencion"):null);

    if(transaccionJson.containsKey("ImporteBruto"))
    {
        JSONObject importeBrutoJson= transaccionJson.get("ImporteBruto");
        Importe importeBruto = new Importe();

        importeBruto.setImporte(importeBrutoJson.containsKey("importe")?importeBrutoJson.get("importe"):null);                        
        importeBruto.setCurrency(importeBrutoJson.containsKey("currency")?importeBrutoJson.get("currency"):null);        
        importeBruto.setRateType(importeBrutoJson.containsKey("rateType")?importeBrutoJson.get("rateType"):null);

        transaccion.setImporteBruto(importeBruto));
    }
    if(transaccionJson.containsKey("importeNeto"))
    {
        Importe importeNeto = new Importe();

        importeNeto.setImporte(importeBrutoJson.containsKey("importe")?importeBrutoJson.get("importe"):null);                        
        importeNeto.setCurrency(importeBrutoJson.containsKey("currency")?importeBrutoJson.get("currency"):null);        
        importeNeto.setRateType(importeBrutoJson.containsKey("rateType")?importeBrutoJson.get("rateType"):null);

        transaccion.setImporteNeto(importeNeto));
    }    
    return transaccion;
}
```

Y ya por ultimo modificamos el metodo construirTabla para recibir el arrayList

```
DefaultTableModel model;    

private void construirTabla(){
    String titulos[]={"TIPO EVENTO SIC","TIPO DERECHO COVACK",
                    "ES_REGIMEN_FISCAL","ORIGEN_DERECHO", 
                    "NOTAS"};
    //Tienes que tener un DefaultTableModel para insertar los datos en la tabla
    model = new DefaultTableModel(titulos,0); 
    ArrayList<Transaccion> informacion=obtenerMatriz();
    miTabla1 = new JTable();
    miBarra.setViewportView(miTabla1);
    miTabla1.setModel(model);

    //Recorremos el list con las transacciones y de transac, extraemos lo que queramos meter en la tabla
    for(Transaccion transac:informacion)
    {
      //Así se añade una nueva fila
      //model.addRow(new Object[]{"campo1","campo2","campo3","campo4","campo5"});
    }

}
```

---

Detalle muy importante, para que se vea la cabercera de las tabla, esta tiene que estar dentro de un `JScrollPane`. Por si te pasa, [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065970/jtable-header-not-showing) la solución.

Como te dije en la otra pregunta, soy mas partidario de usar GSON, ya que por ejemplo, el proceso de convertir el json al objeto Transaccion, habria sido mucho mas facil con GSON ( `Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);`)[Converir json a objeto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object)

Para mas informacion sobre tablas [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Hola Cadeq, lo voy a revisar y acoplar a mi requerimiento, por ejm si quiero acceder al a los elementos que no vienen de JsonArray sino del jsonObject, por ejemplo de la variable "obj" esa misma tambien ya se incluiria dentro de la lista o tendría que hacerse por asi decir algo similiar a como está en jsonArray??? muchas de antemano

Comment: Hola amigo de nuevo el metodo "containsKey" y el get donde se crea? Lo que sucede es que estuve revisando por el del "get" recibe como parámetro un numero, que a lo que entiendo es de donde va a empezar, no sé si este en lo correcto

Comment: @cratus666jose Cuando es un `JsonArray`, en el get se pasa un numero para indicar que elemento del array quieres, mientras que en un `JsonObject` en el get se pasa el nodo que se quiere obtener y se le pasa un object (o un String). Luego, el funcionamiento de un JsonObject es como un `HashMap`, por lo que tiene disponible métodos como `containsKey`, `keySet` o `values`.

Comment: Hola buen dia, entonces para el problema del otro post donde me ayudaste a ponerme ejemplos me marcó un error en el containsKey eso como podría solucionarse, saludos y muchas gracias por la explicación :)

Comment: ¿que error da? Debugea el codigo y mira como llegan los datos cuando se da el error