# Botón buscar y grilla JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy intentando hacer funcionar mi botón **buscar** y la grilla (Una lista donde se muestran los usuarios guardados y/o buscados) pero la verdad es que no he podido enlazarlos. Agradecería si me pueden colaborar.

Acá está el botón buscar y la grilla. La idea es que si no busco nada, me aparezcan todos los registros que tengo guardados. Pero cuando le dé clic al botón **buscar**, sólo lo busque por el **ID Usuario**, y que me traiga en la parte inferior, el registro que solicité.

[image]

Acá el código de lo anterior.

```
package packForms;

import packClases.ClassDatos;
import packClases.Usuario;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FrmUsuarios extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    ClassDatos misDatos = new ClassDatos();

    private int usuaAct = 0;
    private boolean nuevo = false;

    public FrmUsuarios()
        {
        initComponents();
        }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">        
    private void txtIDUsuarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void btnNuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
        //Se crea el usuario y se agrega a datos
        btnPrimer.setEnabled(false);
        btnAnterior.setEnabled(false);
        btnSiguiente.setEnabled(false);
        btnUltimo.setEnabled(false);
        btnModificar.setEnabled(true);
        btnNuevo.setEnabled(true);
        btnBuscar.setEnabled(false);
        btnEliminar.setEnabled(true);

        btnGuardar.setEnabled(true);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);

        //habilitar campos
        txtIDUsuario.setEnabled(true);
        txtNombres.setEnabled(true);
        txtApellidos.setEnabled(true);
        txtClave.setEnabled(true);
        txtConfirmacion.setEnabled(true);
        cmbxPerfil.setEnabled(true);

        //limpiar campos
        txtIDUsuario.setText("");
        txtNombres.setText("");
        txtApellidos.setText("");
        txtClave.setText("");
        txtConfirmacion.setText("");
        cmbxPerfil.setSelectedIndex(0);

        //activamos la variable
        nuevo = true;

        //Se le da focus al campo
        txtIDUsuario.requestFocusInWindow();
    } 

    private void btnCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        //this.dispose();
        //Hay que buscar la forma de limpiar la ventana
        btnPrimer.setEnabled(true);
        btnAnterior.setEnabled(true);
        btnSiguiente.setEnabled(true);
        btnUltimo.setEnabled(true);
        btnModificar.setEnabled(true);
        btnNuevo.setEnabled(true);
        btnBuscar.setEnabled(true);
        btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
        btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);

        //habilitar campos
        txtIDUsuario.setEnabled(false);
        txtNombres.setEnabled(false);
        txtApellidos.setEnabled(false);
        txtClave.setEnabled(false);
        txtConfirmacion.setEnabled(false);
        cmbxPerfil.setEnabled(false);

        //limpiar campos
        txtIDUsuario.setText("");
        txtNombres.setText("");
        txtApellidos.setText("");
        txtClave.setText("");
        txtConfirmacion.setText("");
        cmbxPerfil.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
```

Ahora la otra parte del mismo código

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    //validaciones de campos
    if(txtIDUsuario.getText().equals(""))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe de ingresar un valor");
        txtIDUsuario.requestFocus();
        return;
        }

    if(cmbxPerfil.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe de ingresar un perfil");
        cmbxPerfil.requestFocus();
        return;
        }

    if(txtNombres.getText().equals(""))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe de ingresar un nombre");
        txtNombres.requestFocus();
        return;
        }

    if(txtApellidos.getText().equals(""))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe de ingresar apellidos");
        txtApellidos.requestFocus();
        return;
        }

    String clave = new String(txtClave.getPassword());
    String confirmacion = new String(txtConfirmacion.getPassword());

    if(clave.equals(""))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe de ingresar una contraseña");
        txtClave.requestFocus();
        return;
        }

    if(confirmacion.equals(""))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe de ingresar una contraseña");
        txtConfirmacion.requestFocus();
        return;
        }

    if(!clave.equals(confirmacion))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Clave o confirmación no son iguales");
        txtClave.setText("");
        txtConfirmacion.setText("");
        txtClave.requestFocus();
        return;
        }

    int pos = misDatos.existeUsuario(txtIDUsuario.getText());
    if(nuevo)
        {
        if(pos != -1)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Usuario ya existe.");
            txtIDUsuario.requestFocus();
            return;
            }
        }
        else
            {
            if(pos == -1)
                {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Usuario no existe.");
                txtIDUsuario.requestFocus();
                return;
                }
            }

        //Se crea el objeto de usuario y se agrega a datos
        Usuario miUsuario = new Usuario(txtIDUsuario.getText(),
                txtNombres.getText(), 
                txtApellidos.getText(),
                clave,
                cmbxPerfil.getSelectedIndex());

    String msg; // = misDatos.agregarUsuario(miUsuario);

    if(nuevo)
        {
        msg = misDatos.agregarUsuario(miUsuario);
        }
        else
            {
            msg = misDatos.modificarUsuario(miUsuario, pos);
            }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, msg);

    btnPrimer.setEnabled(true);
    btnAnterior.setEnabled(true);
    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(true);
    btnUltimo.setEnabled(true);
    btnModificar.setEnabled(true);
    btnNuevo.setEnabled(true);
    btnBuscar.setEnabled(true);
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(false);

    //deshabilitar campos
    txtIDUsuario.setEnabled(false);
    txtNombres.setEnabled(false);
    txtApellidos.setEnabled(false);
    txtClave.setEnabled(false);
    txtConfirmacion.setEnabled(false);
    cmbxPerfil.setEnabled(false);
}                                          

private void btnPrimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    usuaAct = 0;
    mostrarRegistro();
} 

private void btnAnteriorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    usuaAct--;

    if(usuaAct == -1)
        {
        usuaAct = misDatos.numeroUsuario() - 1;
        }
    mostrarRegistro();
} 

private void btnSiguienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             usuaAct++;

    if(usuaAct == misDatos.numeroUsuario())
        {
        usuaAct = 0;
        }
    mostrarRegistro();
} 

private void btnUltimoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    usuaAct = misDatos.numeroUsuario() - 1;
    mostrarRegistro();
} 

private void btnModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             nuevo = false;
    btnPrimer.setEnabled(false);
    btnAnterior.setEnabled(false);
    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(false);
    btnUltimo.setEnabled(false);
    btnModificar.setEnabled(true);
    btnNuevo.setEnabled(false);
    btnBuscar.setEnabled(false);
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(true);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);

    //habilitar campos
    txtIDUsuario.setEnabled(true);
    txtNombres.setEnabled(true);
    txtApellidos.setEnabled(true);
    txtClave.setEnabled(true);
    txtConfirmacion.setEnabled(true);
    cmbxPerfil.setEnabled(true);
} 

private void btnEliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    int respuesta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Está seguro de eliminar?");

    if(respuesta != 0)
        {
        return;
        }

    String ms;
    ms = misDatos.eliminarUsuario(usuaAct);
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, ms);

    //Limpiar los registros
    usuaAct = 0;
    mostrarRegistro();
} 

private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    btnPrimer.setEnabled(true);
    btnAnterior.setEnabled(true);
    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(true);
    btnUltimo.setEnabled(true);
    btnModificar.setEnabled(false);
    btnNuevo.setEnabled(false);
    btnBuscar.setEnabled(false);
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(true);
    btnEliminar.setEnabled(true);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);
} 

private String mostrarPerfil(int idPerfil)
    {
    if(idPerfil ==1)
        {
        return "Admin";
        }
    else
        {
        return "Emplead@";
        }
    }
private void mostrarRegistro()
    {
    txtIDUsuario.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuaAct].getIdUsuario());
    txtNombres.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuaAct].getNombres());
    txtApellidos.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuaAct].getApellidos());
    txtClave.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuaAct].getClave());
    txtConfirmacion.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuaAct].getClave());
    cmbxPerfil.setSelectedIndex(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuaAct].getPerfil());
    }

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnAnterior;
private javax.swing.JButton btnBuscar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnCancelar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnEliminar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnModificar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnNuevo;
private javax.swing.JButton btnPrimer;
private javax.swing.JButton btnSiguiente;
private javax.swing.JButton btnUltimo;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbxPerfil;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtApellidos;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtClave;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtConfirmacion;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtIDUsuario;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNombres;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: ¿donde pondrías la id usuario para la búsqueda? lo pregunto por que veo que el campo aparece como des habilitado.

Comment: Me da a entender que los datos se sacan de BBDD. Simplemnete mira que se ha puesto en la busqueda, si esta vacia, haz un `select * from <tabla>`, si esta rellenado, extrae el registro y coloca los valores

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274987/como-llenar-jtable-de-swing-con-valores-de-un-jsonarray-y-jsonobject-en-java/275034#275034) explico en otra tarea como rellenar un jtable (en este caso, con datos de un JSON)

Comment: @Cadeq no tengo base de datos, yo registro un usuario y me queda ahí. Si yo cierro o cancelo el proceso, cuando vuelva a iniciarlo se borra. Es por eso que no sé cómo ejecutar el **buscar** y grabarlo en la tabla

Comment: ¿Y si añades un boton que sea listar y es el que saca el listado?

Comment: El problema es que como apenas estoy iniciando con JAVA, no lo entiendo mucho que digamos.